# Code for web crawling with Python 2.7.3 in mac terminal?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, wget, web-crawler

I am a social scientist and a complete newbie/noob when it comes to coding. I have searched through the other questions/tutorials but am unable to get the gist of how to crawl a news website targeting the comments section specifically. Ideally, I'd like to tell python to crawl a number of pages and return all the comments as a .txt file. I've tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://www.xxxxxx.com"
```

and that's as far as I can go before I get an error message saying `bs4` is not a module. I'd appreciate any kind of help on this, and please, if you decide to respond, DUMB IT DOWN for me!

I can run `wget` on terminal and get all kinds of text from websites which is awesome IF I could actually figure out how to save the individual output html files into one big .txt file. I will take a response to either question.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you installed Beautiful Soup? It doesn't come with python...

Comment: "Comments" will not be auto-magically handled by a web scraper. You'll almost definitely need to write site-specific code to extract the comments.

Comment: If you're just starting out with Python, and don't have a real compelling reason to use 2.7.3, I'd strongly suggest learning Python 3. It's the future of the language, more and more modules are being ported to it every day, joining the large number that already work with it, and it takes care of a lot of issues (like unicode) that pop up when using Python 2. [Download version 3.3.0](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/) and get going!

Comment: Moshe - do you have any links to good web tutorials for scraping using python?

Comment: MattDMo - I'm only using the said version of python because that's pre-installed on my MacBook and runs thru the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It is a fast high-level screen scraping and web crawling framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages. It can be used for a wide range of purposes, from data mining to monitoring and automated testing.

Comment: OK thanks for the responses. I am using OS 10.7.5 and having issues installing Scrapy. Will go back over the instructions though.

Comment: Nilesh - do you have any helpful tips on how to install scrapy on Mac? I am completely useless in understanding how to do it. I have no idea where to put the "pip install". I'm sorry I really have no knowledge when it comes to this thing :(

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely encounter this as you go, but in some cases, if the site is employing 3rd party services for comments, like Disqus, you will find that you will not be able to pull the comments down in this manner. Just a heads up.

I've gone down this route before and have had to tailor the script to a particular site's layout/design/etc.

I've found libcurl to be extremely handy, if you don't mind doing the post-processing using Python's string handler functions.

If you don't need to implement it purely in Python, you can make use of wget's recursive mirroring option to handle the content pull, then write your python code to parse the downloaded files.

Comment: WTW, thank you so much for the heads up. I can run wget to mirror the articles and comments successfully but was wondering if you could further explain, if possible, if/how I could tell wget to save the HTML pages as one continuous .txt file. Also, how involved would the python code be for sparsing/deleting the articles and keeping only the comments? I realize these are crazy questions but I'm just trying to get a better idea of how I can go about doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my two cents here as well.

The first things to check are that you installed beautiful soup, and that it lives somewhere that it can be found. There's all kinds of things that can go wrong here.

My experience is similar to yours: I work at a web startup, and we have a bunch of users who register, but give us no information about their job (which is actually important for us). So my idea was to scrape the homepage and the "About us" page from the domain in their email address, and try to put a learning algorithm around the data that I captured to predict their job. The results for each domain are stored as a text file.

Unfortunately (for you...sorry), the code I ended up with was a bit complicated. The problem is that you'll end up getting a lot of garbage when you do the scraping, and you'll have to filter it out. You'll also end up with encoding issues, and (assuming you want to do some learning here) you'll have to get rid of low-value words. The total code is about 1000 lines, and I'll post some important pieces that may help you out here, if you're interested.

Comment: 1000 lines wow! I think I may be better off getting a license for Helium to handle all the scraping!

Comment: Well, to be clear: this was the entire script, which had to pull info from our DB, aside from cleaning the data up and implementing the learning algorithm. I was assuming you wanted to do something similar--namely, implement a learning routine around something you scrape from the internet. The scraping code by itself was around 100-150 lines.